# How can my character cool her tea quickly?

Tags: hard-science, thermodynamics

Let's say I have a character that is obsessed with drinking warm tea (or cider, or...).

Tea needs to be steeped at a high temperature; say, 90°c. However, drinking it at that temperature will result in burns. My character would prefer to drink her tea at 50°c... and she's impatient. Sipping it slowly or waiting for it to cool down naturally are considered "unacceptable" options.

Let's also say this character isn't completely unique, but that most people aren't willing to go out of their way to cool tea. Whatever solution you concoct, if it isn't inherently dirt cheap, will be used by approximately the same people that buy $1,000 coffee machines for their homes. In other words, a niche market, but not a bespoke market.

Solutions should meet the following criteria:

- Can cool 1 liter of beverage in "a few" minutes. Ideally, one, but not more than five. Ideally would work on volumes up to 4 liters, but not strictly necessary.
- **DOES NOT** dilute the beverage. Simply chucking in shaved ice is *not* an option.
- Can either be trivially Jerry-rigged, or can be produced and marketed for about $500 or less. (Assume US dollars with circa 2019 purchasing power.)
- Use of pre-chilled materials is fine, as long as you stick to residential freezers (-15°c - -20°c, and has to fit in the freezer). Ideally, such materials can be ready for reuse in 4-6 hours.
- Use of electricity is fine as long as you stick to reasonable residential consumption (~1,000 W for no more than a few minutes).

---

[hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science): Please show, with math, that your proposed solutions are feasible. For example, if your solution involves introducing a large, cold, non-soluble object, or using some sort of refrigerator, please show via heat transfer modeling that it can meet the time requirement.

Assume the physical properties of the beverage are essentially the same as water. Here are some bits to get you started:

- $c_{beverage} = 4,184 \frac J {kg \cdot K}$
- $T_{initial} = 90°c = 363 K$
- $T_{desired} = 50°c = 323 K$
- This means an ideal solution can remove $167,360 \frac J L$. To accomplish our goal of cooling one liter per minute, that works out to about 2,800 watts.

Comment: Math makes this difficult but I am just thinking those whisky stone things you use for alcohol to not dilute it with ice water.  If they always were cooled to the same temperature, then it is just a matter of using more or less of them to reach the temperature you want.  Personally when someone tells me their drink is too hot, I pour it into another mug.  Problem solved.

Comment: There's a whole slew of realworld answers to this (with the single substitution of coffee instead of tea) on the cooking SE, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116437/cooling-coffee-rapidly-without-dilution/

Comment: @Trevor: +1 for the whisky stones. You are right that any cooling capacity desired can be achieved by using enough stones, and if the original querent needs math I will point out that the real numbers form an [Archimedean field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), and this was known since the Antiquity. (Informally, it means that many a mickle makes a muckle.) If they don't like whisky stones they can always circulate the fluid to be cooled through a sufficiently long metal pipe, which can obviously also be made to achieve any cooling capacity desired, for the same reason.

Comment: It looks like your world is already built and you're asking how a character can solve an in-world problem.

Comment: P.S. In formal writing it should be [*jury*-rigged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging), not *jerry*-rigged. Wouldn't have bothered me if it was not tagged hard science, which implies a higher linguistic register.

Comment: @AlexP Would it work if you had a long metal straw, placed one cup above the other, and used a gravity syphon to move the tea to the bottom cup and cool it?  With the length of the straw and the angle of the drop controlling the cooling?

Comment: What is even "world building" about this question?

Comment: @coppereyecat, well, Physics.SE apparently hates "specific" questions, which makes it hard to reality-check any proposed solution. I'm not sure where *else* to ask?

Comment: @Trevor, I'm pretty sure whiskey stones don't transfer heat *fast* enough. Good for *keeping* things cold, not so good for cooling them in a hurry. For that, you need high surface area.

Comment: I forgot about saucering. the act of pouring some tea onto a saucer then drinking from there. Cheap, was done.

Answer (score 2):

**Are you sure about the 2800W ?**

Q: *"Can cool 1 liter of beverage in "a few" minutes. Ideally, one"*

I expect you can do with far less, if you have a full 60 seconds.

**Proposed experiment**

There's easy heat transfer. Let's avoid ceramics, glass, or paper,

.. take a metal tea pot, cylindrical, single wand

[image]

Use a champaign cooler,

https://www.google.com/search?q=champagne+cooler

Or place it in an *electric* champagne cooler,

https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Ambient-Electric-Champagne-Cooling-Lighting/dp/B07GT6WCJW

Not *instantly*.. but your tea will get cold very quickly !

If a champagne cooler don't work, try a wodka-cooler, very effective (used in bars), you'll have to scale it up, though..

[image]

If it won't work.. try a 40x40cm industrial piezo electric cooler, 60 Watts will do fine.
If THAT won't work.. order a piezo electric cooler in the shape of your tea pot. It will cost a fortune..

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling

If nothing works, consider medical equipment.. Cryogenic Liquid Nitrogen Container Ln2

[image]

To contain a liter, you'd need a big one.

I propose above experiment.. but I actually don't know if existing cooling equipment can extract heat using *2800W* from a tea pot, the wands are limited in area.

**Space**

When the wait is still too long, I'd suggest to buy yourself a tourist ticket to the International Space Station, and arrange to hold your pot of tea outside. Be *quick*, though.. don't let it freeze and evaporate ! Make sure you wear gloves

[image]

Comment: I think the pot of tea would explode in space due to pressure…

Comment: "Are you sure about the 2800W?" Pretty sure. 1 L of water has a heat capacity of 4,184 J/K. If I want to drop that 40 K (when talking temperature *differences*, °c and K are interchangeable), that's 167,360 J (for one liter). A Watt is a Joule per second; to drop that in one *second* would need ~167 kW... but that's unnecessarily fast. Allowing more time reduces the power proportionately, i.e. 167,360 J / 60 s ≈ 2,800 W.

Comment: Yeah well @Nephanth +1, the astronauts who serves our table and brings us our tea will probably have a trick for that (In other words: I must hand-waive the procedure, lol)

Comment: @Matthew we agree about heat capacity, but I wonder if you need to put that power into the process, while your actual intent is to get energy *out*. Lowering temperature means transport of heat, not generation of heat.

Comment: I need to *extract* that energy. Ideally using something with a [CoP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance) of ~3, such that it only needs ~900 W of electricity. A TEC assuredly won't work; their CoP is less than 1 (and worse for large temperature gradients).

Comment: To put that differently, the desired cooling capability is ~9,500 BTU/hr, or just over ¾ ton. A window air conditioner in that range is ~$1,000 and *at least* the size of a typical microwave. So, simply throwing a heat pump at the problem is probably not the answer. The problem almost certainly requires either being clever, or using something that's already at a low temperature. (And, yes, I thought about cryogenic liquids, but that doesn't seem very practical.)

Comment: @Matthew maybe a stupid plan but did you consider adiabatic expansion ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process

Answer (score 2):

Bowl of ice.  On top, a flat saucer.  Pour the hot tea in.  The more shallow the saucer and so the greater the surface area, the quicker it will be.

Comment: I also feel this would work (also a solution without the 2800W) but the opener states *"Simply chucking in shaved ice is not an option."* ..

Comment: @Goodies Pour the tea onto the saucer which is on the ice, not directly onto the ice.

Comment: Oh ok so you only make a larger surface. Good plan..

Comment: A bowl full of watery crushed ice *plus salt* (a.k.a. freezing mixture) should work even faster.

Comment: The hard-science tag "... requires answers backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc." This answer as is has none of that and should technically be downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a large canister with a hand pump and cooling fins. Manually (or electrically) pump the canister full and let it cool.

The tea can be then poured in a container with a perforated partition on the bottom, so that the compressed air bubbles through the tea, expanding and cooling. Having lots of tiny bubbles ensures that the heat exchange rate is very high.

A costlier version might employ e.g. small disposable canisters of compressed nitrogen.

Comment: Can you show how effective this would be? How much air would you need, how quickly would it work, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't the character just use a modifed heat exchanger? AKA HVAC, refrigerator etc.

For the specific device:
Just need a top reservoir that user can dump drink into or another device can dump into. A middle heat exchanger block that pre regulated to be suitable for the drink temperature.  Then lower chamber with a valve at the top where cup is placed to receive the temperature adjusted beverage. When the lower change valve is opened the cup is filled. Additionally another block or two for controller, pumps and other side of the heat reservoir.

There would need to be some calibration for the characteristics of the fluid being adjusted.

The heat exchanger if having sufficiently high surface area should and pre heated should be able to chill the beverage in a few seconds. The concern here is the higher the surface area the higher maintenance will be, hard water scaling could kill this device. This would limit the ranges of beverages that could be chilled.

Prices of these units would be 5 to 10 times as expensive as a home free-standing air conditioner. Mostly due to low demand for a product like this.

But essentially this is just A home AC unit that is designed for beverage cooling, not air  and with a target closer to 50c rather then 21c.

Comment: Household refrigerator won't do. Tried it with a metal teapot. Tea is 70 degrees after 60 sec, not 50.

Comment: Why? I think you already hit on the answer; they'd be too expensive. Not to mention possibly too *big* to fit in any reasonable-sized kitchen.